# Attempt to echo a string that might be tainted

Tags: php

I got the error "Attempt to echo a string that might be tainted", the error line is,

```
<form action="?action=export&val=<?php echo $_GET['val'];?>&export=yes" method="post">
```

How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have enabled [Taint](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.taint.php) functions. It will issue warning if you pass potential XSS codes (tainted strings) to functions.

You can disable it by setting `taint.enable` = `0` in php.ini

As suggested by other users, use of `urlencode()`, `urlrawencode()` (note the difference), `htmlspecialchars()` can eliminate the warning. Also, if you want to use the `$_GET`, `$_POST` variable in database, be sure to escape it by `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or use prepared statement or use PDO.

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to the fact that the variable is inserted into the URL exactly the way the user has specified, which is a potential security risk. Use [`urlencode($_GET['val'])`](http://php.net/urlencode) instead, to escape the value and thus neutralize the risk.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Taint extention enabled :

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.taint.php

Try using htmlspecialchars() when doing echo(s)

Answer (score 0):

Do not directly use `$_GET[]` variables, but first process them, validate that there's no SQL injection or other harmful stuff, then display processed value.